# String assembly

Tags: string, search, assembly, char

The task is to search a string and find if inputted char is in the string MES3 or not.Here is my code , but it doesn`t  search all letters in the string just the first .How can i make the cycle to work and search through all symbols in the string

```
 masm 
model small
.DATA 
MSG1 DB 10,13,'CHARACTER FOUND :) $'
MSG2 DB 10,13,'CHARACTER NOT FOUND :($'
MSG3 DB 10,13,'there is no hope of doing this bla  : $'
MSG4 DB 10,13,'ENTER THE CHARACTER  TO BE SEARCHED : $'
NEW  DB 10,13,'$'
NEW1 DB 10,13,'$'
NEW2 DB 10,13,'$'



 .CODE 
 ASSUME CS:@CODE,DS:@DATA
 START:
  MOV AX,@DATA
  MOV DS,AX
  LEA di,[MSG3]

DOWN:
  LEA dx,NEW
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H
  LEA DX,MSG4
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H

  MOV AH,01H
  INT 21H

  MOV DI,0
 UP1:

  CMP AL,[MSG3+di]
  JE DOWN3
  INC DI
  LOOP UP1
  LEA DX,MSG2
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H
  JMP FINISH

 DOWN3:
  LEA DX,MSG1
  MOV AH,09H
  INT 21H
 FINISH:
   INT 3

   mov AX, 4c00h
   int 21h
   END START
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LOOP` instruction (that you use in `LOOP UP1`) decrements `CX` and jumps to the target label if `CX != 0`. So you need to set `CX` to the maximum number of characters to compare before the `UP1` label.

Or you could replace `LOOP UP1` with `CMP BYTE PTR [MSG3-1+di],'$'` / `JNE UP1` since the string is '$'-terminated.

Comment: thanks but it still doesn`t work .i  set CX to be 34  but it is the same still don`t recognize other symbol than the first

Comment: It works for me. If I enter e.g. a `b`, the program prints `CHARACTER FOUND :)`. If I enter something that's not in `MSG3`, like a `q`, it says `CHARACTER NOT FOUND :(`.

Comment: i did it again and this time it worked thank you so much